# Under what conditions is this abuse of notation invalid?

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

Let's say that we have an integral:

$$\int \cos(\omega x) \mathrm{e}^{a x} dx $$

One method of working this integral is to use integration by parts twice to obtain a copy of the original integral, but that's long and kind of annoying:

$$\begin{split}
\int \cos(\omega x) \mathrm{e}^{a x} dx &= \frac1{a} \cos(\omega x) \mathrm{e}^{a x} - \int -\frac{\omega}{a} \sin(\omega x) \mathrm{e}^{a x} dx \\
 &= \frac1{a} \cos(\omega x) \mathrm{e}^{a x} + \frac{\omega}{a} \int \sin(\omega x) \mathrm{e}^{a x} dx \\
 &= \frac1{a} \cos(\omega x) \mathrm{e}^{a x} + \frac{\omega}{a} \left(\frac1{a} \sin(\omega x) \mathrm{e}^{a x} - \int \frac{\omega}{a} \cos(\omega x) \mathrm{e}^{a x} dx\right) \\
 &= \frac1{a} \cos(\omega x) \mathrm{e}^{a x} + \frac{\omega}{a^2} \sin(\omega x) \mathrm{e}^{a x} - \frac{\omega^2}{a^2} \int\ \cos(\omega x) \mathrm{e}^{a x} dx \\
\left(a^2 + \omega^2\right)\int \cos(\omega x) \mathrm{e}^{a x} dx &= a \cos(\omega x) \mathrm{e}^{a x} + \omega \sin(\omega x) \mathrm{e}^{a x} \\
\int \cos(\omega x) \mathrm{e}^{a x} dx &= \frac{a}{a^2 + \omega^2} \cos(\omega x) \mathrm{e}^{a x} + \frac{\omega}{a^2 + \omega^2} \sin(\omega x) \mathrm{e}^{a x} \\
\end{split}$$

Instead, we can use the complex domain and compute (assuming $x$ is real):

$$\int \Re\left\{\mathrm{e}^{i \omega x}\right\} \mathrm{e}^{a x} dx $$

And assuming that $a$ is also a real number we can bring it into the Real part and compute the integral simply:

$$\begin{split}
 &= \int \Re\left\{\mathrm{e}^{(a + i \omega) x}\right\} dx \\
 &= \Re\left\{\frac1{a + i \omega}\mathrm{e}^{(a + i \omega) x}\right\} \\
 &= \Re\left\{\frac{a - i \omega}{a^2 + \omega^2} \mathrm{e}^{ i \omega x} \mathrm{e}^{a x}\right\} \\
 &= \frac{a}{a^2 + \omega^2} \cos(\omega x) \mathrm{e}^{ax} + \frac{\omega}{a^2 + \omega^2} \sin(\omega x) \mathrm{e}^{a x} \\
\end{split}$$

But if $a$ is not a real number then bringing $\mathrm{e}^{a t}$ into the $\Re$ isn't allowed.  But we get the same answer.  So if we try to compute the integral in this way it's an abuse of notation.  It does work in this instance, and other simple cases like $x \cos(\omega x) \mathrm{e}^{a x}$.

Because this sort of integrand appears in the Laplace Transform reasonably commonly, it might be useful to know when this sort of abuse will work, and when it breaks down.

(Yes, it is possible to also just use the identity $\cos(\omega x) = \frac1{2} \left( \mathrm{e}^{i \omega x} + \mathrm{e}^{-i \omega x} \right)$ and while that's easier than the integration by parts, it's more involved than the abuse.)

Comment: Interesting question, I never gave it much thought. I suppose you could use an argument with analytic continuation.

Comment: I spoke with someone who's taken complex analysis, and they said that given a function: $f(x) \cos(x) \mathrm{e}^{ax}$ they didn't see a reason why it wouldn't be valid if $f(x)$ were real valued analytic on the (assumed real valued) domain of integration.  Does this sound reasonable?  It sounds like a strong conclusion, but I don't have the background to address it.

Comment: Sounds reasonable since the integral of an analytic function is also analytic.

Comment: So it's sufficient but not necessary?  (As I assume there exists functions who are not analytic, but whose integrals are.)

Comment: Yes, that is the case.